# Working with typescript non-discriminated unions

Tags: typescript, type-inference, unions

I wonder if there's a sane way how to get the following to work.

```
interface IPerson {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}

interface IPet {
  name: string
}

type IPersonOrPet = IPerson | IPet

function fullname(p: IPersonOrPet) {
  if (p.name) {                                     // **1**
    return p.name                                   // **2**
  } else {
    return p.firstName + ' ' + p.lastName           // **3**
  }
}
```

I see that with discriminated unions, sich things are simple, but I can't see why nothing works for non-discriminated unions:

- **1** I could imagine, that typescript complains here because of not knowing whether `p.name` exists. But isn't there a better way than using `any`?
- **2** However, here it knows that it exists and is non-empty. Such inference works in many places, why not here?
- **3** This is obviously wrong, because it gets reached for an unnamed pet (i.e., `{name: ''}`). As I don't know how to solve the two previous points, I could only guess here.

Comment: Interfaces in TypeScript are very different from C#/Java `interface`-types and don’t use the `I`-prefix. And generally speaking, TypeScript interfaces should be named after their capabilities instead of concrete nouns, so in this case I’d have `interface HasPersonalName { firstName: string; lastName: string; }` - as well as adding `type ReadOnlyPersonalName = ReadOnly<HasPersonalName>;` (mapped-types are invaluable for brevity _and_ preventing bugs caused by forgetting members in a mapping)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [use the `in` operator as a type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator) which typescript will use to properly narrow the types within the condition bodies.

```
function fullname(p: IPersonOrPet) {
  if ('name' in p) {                                // **1**
    return p.name                                   // **2**
  } else {
    return p.firstName + ' ' + p.lastName           // **3**
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to address this in TypeScript is to use a type guard, a function whose return type confirms or rejects your hypothesis that `p` belongs to `Person` or to `Pet`.

Check out the return type of the `isPerson()` function:

```
interface Person {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}

interface Pet {
  name: string
}

type PersonOrPet = Person | Pet

function fullname(p: PersonOrPet) {
  if (isPerson(p)) {
    return p.firstName + ' ' + p.lastName;
  } else {
    return p.name;
  }
}

function isPerson(p: PersonOrPet): p is Person {
  return 'firstName' in p && 'lastName' in p;
}
```